# How to prove combinatorial $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} {n\choose2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2 - 1} {n\choose2k+1} = 2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have problems solving the following formula for even positive integers $n$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} {n\choose 2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2 - 1} {n\choose 2k+1} = 2^{n-1}$$

I tried to prove it by induction but it didn't work. Is there any combinatorial proof?

Comment: You can use the symmetry of the binomial coefficients to show the first equality. Then you can use the binomial theorem to show that the sum of the first two is equal to $2^n$ and conclude the second equality using the first one.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ denote a set of size $n\ge 1$. Your first sum is the number of even-size subsets of $S$; the second sum counts the odd-size subsets instead. Fix some $a\in S$, then pair each $x\subseteq S\backslash\{a\}$ with $x\cup\{a\}$. Since each pair is one odd-sized set and one even-sized set, there are equally many of each, and that's $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

For brevity we prove $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{2k+1} = 2^{2n-1},\hspace{2cm}(*)$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It is sufficient to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}=2^{2n-1}$ since we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} = 2^{2n}.\hspace{2cm}(**)$$ Let apply induction for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}=2^{2n-1}$.
For $n=1$ equality is true. For $n=m$ assume equality is true, namely $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m}{2k}=2^{2m-1}$(Here note that $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m}{2k+1}=2^{2m-1}$ is also true by (**)). For $n=m+1$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m+2}{2k}&=&\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\left\{ \binom{2m}{2k-1}+\binom{2m}{2k-2}+\binom{2m}{2k}+\binom{2m}{2k-1}\right\}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m}{2k}+ 2\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m}{2k-2}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m}{2k}+ 2\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} \binom{2m}{2k-2}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m}{2k}+2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m}{2k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2m}{2k}\\
&=&4.2^{2m-1}=2^{2m+1}\end{eqnarray*} by use of $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$. Hence equality $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}=2^{2n-1}$ is valid for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which implies $(*)$.

Comment: Could you please explain the transformation in more detail from $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} {n\choose2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2 - 1} {n\choose2k+1} = 2^{n-1}$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n\choose2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n - 1} {2n\choose2k+1} = 2^{2n-1}$

Comment: Since you take $n$ as even natural number in your question, we can make transformation $n=2m$ where $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, your formula transforms accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
You can get the result by expanding these two expressions using the binomial theorem
$$(1-1)^n=0\ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ (1+1)^n=2^n.$$